# How to fix update statement with passwords

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access-2007

So my problem is that is says that there is my problem in my update statement, but I believe that my statement is right, if I am wrong please correct  me

```
                            connection.Open();
                            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                            command.Connection = connection;
                            string query = "update Admin set Password='" + Npassword.Text + "' WHERE Pk='" + txt2.Text + "'";
                            command.CommandText = query;
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MessageBox.Show("Password Changed");
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error, fill the fields required" + ex);
                            connection.Close();
                        }
```

Comment: Are you using MySql or MS Access? Either way, use parameterized SQL queries and your problem will probably be solved. In future, please show the error message you receive, as it's hard to diagnose your issue without.

Comment: Your query is outrightly inviting for a sql injection attack. Follow @John's suggestion of using parametrized queries. Alternatively you could wrap update statement within a stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring for a moment the good advice in the comments, *Password* is a reserved word in Access SQL, thus must be bracketed:

```
string query = "update Admin set [Password]='" + Npassword.Text + "' WHERE Pk='" + txt2.Text + "'";
```

Also, if *Pk* is numeric, no quotes:

```
string query = "update Admin set [Password]='" + Npassword.Text + "' WHERE Pk=" + txt2.Text + "";
```